# The number of $x$ for which $-4x$ and $-4x+1$ are quadratic residues mod some odd prime number

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. What is the number $N_p$ of $x\in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ for which $-4x$ and $-4x+1$ are quadratic residues modulo $p$?
Some computations give me :
$$N_3=N_5=0,N_7=1,N_{11}=N_{13}=2,N_{17}=3,N_{19}=4,N_{23}=5,N_{29}=6,N_{31}=7,N_{37}=8$$
$$N_{41}=9, N_{43}=10, N_{47}=11,N_{53}=12,N_{59}=N_{61}=14$$
I couldn't drive any formula from this data in terms of $p$. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

From your numerical data we obviously have $N_p=\lfloor \frac{p-3}{4}\rfloor$. Can you prove this, using elementary number theory?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to prove this but I failed. Could you explain how that can be proven?

Comment: Use the Legendre symbol. We have $(-4x/p)=(-1/p)(4x/p)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}(4x/p)=1$. How many $x\in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^{\times}$ satisfy this? How many $x'$ satisfy $(x'/p)=1$?

Comment: I know that there is $(p-1)/2$, $x\in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ satisfying $(-4x/p)=1$ and $(p-3)/2$, $x$ satisfying $(-4x+1/p)=1$.